# speed-up computation of sum over several subsets

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, data-structures

Let's say I have a huge array of doubles w[] indexed from 0 to n-1.

I also have a list of m subsets of [0;n-1]. For each subset S, I am trying to compute the sums of w[i] over S.

Obviously I can compute this separately for each subset, which is going to be in O(m * n).

However is there any faster way to do this? I'm talking from a practical standpoint, as I think you can't have a lower asymptotic bound. Is it possible to pre-process all the subsets and store them in such a way that computing all the sums is faster?

Thanks!

edit : 
to give some order of magnitude, my n would be around 20 millions, and m around ~200.

Comment: Do you count parallelization as a solution? It would be easy to parallelize this.

Comment: Any reason you have tagged this with 3 languages, all of which are different from each other?

Comment: That second paragraph is confusing… is `n` the same for both arrays, or is the length really m-1 not n-1?

Comment: It the data is independent or a single large chunk: it would seem to be possible to parallelize it then sum the partial sums. It might also be be possible to *vectorize* - does your CPU support AVX/AVX2? Note: doing this in C will be different to doing this in C++ will be different to doing this in C#

Comment: Are the subsets dense (i.e., all the items from some starting point to some stopping point), or is each subset a sparse list of indices into `w` (or similar)?

Comment: Note that the sum of more than two `double`s is order-sensitive (i.e. not associative).  In general, then, you will get a different answer if you perform the additions in a different order.  That includes if you subdivide into non-overlapping sections and then add subtotals, or if you perform similar algebraic tricks.

Comment: @Micrified I don't :p

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm more interested in a solution that doesn't rely on SIMD

Comment: @lezebulon Then you could try appending all subsets together in one vector given they're the same length, then sum along that. Would save you hopping around in memory. But not by much.

Comment: @JerryCoffin In my use case, I'd have maybe half of the subsets being fairly "dense" as you define it and the other half being "sparse"... I can't really assume any specificities unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For subsets that are dense (or nearly dense) you may be able to speed up the computation by computing a running sum of the elements. That is, create another array in parallel with `w`, where each element in the parallel array contains the sum of the elements of `w` up to that point.

To compute the sum for a dense subset, you that the starting and ending positions in the parallel array, and subtract the running sum at the start from the running sum at the end. The difference between the two is (ignoring rounding errors) the sum for that subset.

For a nearly dense subset, you start by doing the same, then subtract off the values of the (relatively few) items in that range that aren't part of the set.

These may not produce exactly the same result as you'd get by naively summing the subset though. If you need better accuracy, you'd probably want to use Kahan summation for your array of running sums, and possibly preserve its error residual at each point, to be taken into account when doing the subtraction.